# WPF C# Cefsharp Ver. 71, each load of user control creates new CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

Please check the code snippets below, this get loaded everytime i navigate to my view(user control) and it creates new CefSharp.BrowserProcess.exe on each load and renders last visited URL. 
Problem with is is that it does not maintain the session storage of the site (URL) And load is incorrect with data is lost.

viewModel (main) code:

```
private void OnLoad()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TieAddress))
            {
                TieAddress = _serviceJournalsBaseSettings.GetTieUrl();
            }

            var cookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie
            {
                Name = BaseSettings.GetTieCookieName(),
                Value = BaseSettings.GetTieCookie()
            };
            cookieManager.SetCookie(BaseSettings.GetTieCookieUrl(), cookie);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowErrorNotification(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

View (User control) Code:

```
 <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser 
 Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
 x:Name="BrowserTieView"

                            Address="{Binding TieAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Title="Browser Tie View"
                            AllowDrop="True"/>
```

View.Xaml.cs

```
public partial class ServiceJournalsView : UserControl
{
    public ServiceJournalsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BrowserTieView.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        BrowserTieView.BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings()
        {
            ApplicationCache = CefState.Enabled,
            FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            Javascript = CefState.Enabled,
            LocalStorage = CefState.Enabled,
            WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled,
            JavascriptCloseWindows = CefState.Enabled,
            JavascriptDomPaste = CefState.Enabled,
        };

        BrowserTieView.LoadError += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Don't display an error for downloaded files.
            if (args.ErrorCode == CefErrorCode.Aborted)
            {
                return;
            }


            // Display a load error message.
            var errorBody = string.Format(
                "<html><body bgcolor=\"white\"><h2>Failed to load URL {0} with error {1} ({2}).</h2></body></html>",
                args.FailedUrl, args.ErrorText, args.ErrorCode);

            args.Frame.LoadHtml(errorBody, base64Encode: true);
        };
        Unloaded += async delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            BrowserTieView.WebBrowser.Dispose();
            BrowserTieView.Dispose();
            await Task.Delay(10);
        };


    }

    public ServiceJournalsViewModel VMServiceJournalsViewModel
    {
        get => (ServiceJournalsViewModel) DataContext;
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BrowserTieView.RegisterJsObject("serviceJournalsJsModel", VMServiceJournalsViewModel.ServiceJournalsJsModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `CachePath`?

Comment: @amaitland, hi, its not set, so i believe it is picking default setting for the same.

Comment: There is no default,  an in memory cache is used https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs#L16

Comment: @amaitland if i set it then Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe will be created only once and will not be created mutliple times( one for each new load of user control), is that what you saying?

Comment: No. Multiple instances of `Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` is perfectly normal. Persisting the state is the only thing you should be worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments of the question posted( and as per @amaitland) Multiple instances of Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe is perfectly normal.